# Random crash: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, stack-trace, nszombie

I have a crash that randomly appears... I'm using this library for a tutorial:
https://github.com/MatthewYork/MYBlurIntroductionView

Since the error is not so obvious, and placing several NSLog in my code and in this library doesn't help, I come here with my logs and hope that you will be able to help me!

The crash sometime occurs when I try to swipe from slide 1 to slide 2.

```
*** -[UIViewControllerBuiltinTransitionViewAnimator respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7a70ba60
```

The stacktrace can be found here: 
[image]

Running NSZombie gives me this result:

[image]

For me it's just Chinese, but if you have any tips about this crash that would be awesome!

Update : I'm running the tutorial code in the completion block of

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *rawData, NSError *error)
```

with this code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      TutorialViewController* myTutorial = [[TutorialViewController alloc] init];

      [self presentViewController:myTutorial animated:NO completion:nil];
});
```

With or without the dispatch_async, the problem sometimes occurs.

[image]

Comment: My guess is that you're doing GUI operations from a background thread. In particular, the line mentioning `NSURLConnection` and its completion handler is suspicious. You can select each line of the Zombie events and look at the stack trace to see on which thread it's occurring.

Comment: I have updated my post with information about my threads... Maybe I'm doing something wrong here?

Comment: Have you added an exception breakpoint to catch where it is happening?

Comment: Maybe you are using a UIAlertView with a delegate to a “specialy” ViewController… what is dealocated/dismissed some time (when you click a button from UIAlertView)….

Comment: In fine, even If I remove everything about the UIAlertView delegate, I have the same problem. 
Exception break point only gives me a few information (cf screenshot)

Comment: @KenThomases is very likely correct here. You're probably calling a UIKit method on a background thread, which is undefined behavior for UIKit, and this is just the kind of symptom you'd expect to see. Audit your code for UIKit calls that aren't explicitly put onto the main thread.

Comment: Do you think it's related to the tutorial? 
The tutorial is displayed in main thread, no UIALertView is displayed, no UIAlertView delegate is set, and I don't run anything before this tutorial (which worked fine a few days ago btw)

Comment: I recomend you to change MYBlurIntroductionView to other.... :) Did you saw the note on their page? NOTICE: As of February 4th, Apple has begun to ban new app submissions using the common blurring method (UIToolbar hack) found in MYBlurIntroductionView. We will work toward a new solution, but unfortunately this library has removed the blurring functionality until a solution is found. Cheers.

Comment: I think you're right @TonyMkenu, I'm pretty sure the problem comes from MYBLurIntroductionView.

@ all : Thanks a lot for your help and time.

Comment: I have the same problem. I did something uses `self` after `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`, just moved them before dismiss viewcontroller.